# How can I parse a string in ansible?

Tags: shell, ansible, yaml

I use the `openssl` command to retrieve data and register the result in ansible. I receive the following output:

```
#cert.stdout_lines
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            ed:92:fe:51:b1:d1:6c:91:03:00:00:00:00:cb:f7:b1
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 13 10:17:32 2021 GMT
            Not After : Jul  6 10:17:31 2021 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
```

I want to use certain fields such as `CN`, `Not Before` and `Not After`. So I tried to get the data-structure as YAML, but that does not work.

```
set_fact:
  test: "{{ cert.stdout_lines | from_yaml }}
```

How I can use data from that command in ansible?
(I can't use the `get_cert` module in ansible because of python restrictions and I can't modify the python-version.)

Comment: Use [x509_certificate_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_info_module.html#community-crypto-x509-certificate-info-provide-information-of-openssl-x-509-certificates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use a module, but as you say you can not do that, here is how to do it without using one:

`from_yaml` will parse valid yaml into a dictionary. Your data is not in the yaml-format, so `from_yaml` does not work.

If you need to use the openssl-command, you will need to use a regex to parse the data. You can do that by using `grep` in the shell-module or the `regex_search` filter in ansible. As we want to use as much ansible as possible, I'll show how to do it with a filter:

```yaml
set_fact:
  not_before: "{{ cert.stdout_lines | regex_search('(?<=Not Before: ).*') }}"
  not_after: "{{ cert.stdout_lines | regex_search('(?<=Not After: ).*') }}"
  subject: "{{ cert.stdout_lines | regex_search('(?<=Subject: ).*') | regex_search('(?<=CN = ).*')}}"
```

Check out the documentation of [python regexes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and ansible's [regex filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions).

Comment: @nismoa Running openssl in shell is a bad practice in ansible. Use the dedicated module as already advised in Vladimir's comment.

Answer (score -1):

Write a wrapper script to run your openssl command and parse its output, then have the wrapper script output the needed info in valid yaml.